# Leaflet MarkerCluster - how to get markers inside cluster on event (mouseover, mouseclick)?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I need to get the markers inside a cluster when the specific event is fired (`clustermouseover` or `clusterclick`). I was examining the event object `e` in developer console, but `e.layer._markers` is an empty array.

```
group_markers.on('clustermouseover', function (e) {
    console.log('clustermouseover');
    console.log(e);
});
```

`group_markers` is the `L.markerClusterGroup` object.

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `getAllChildMarkers` method of the layer object (`e.layer`). Example:

```
markers.on('clustermouseover', function (e) {
    console.log('Number of markers: ' + e.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});
```

According to the [Leaflet.markercluster docs](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#other-clusters-methods)

> getAllChildMarkers: Returns the array of total markers contained within that cluster.

Here's [a JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qasuvur/3/edit?js,console,output) with a working example.

An underscore (`_`) is usually used to denote that an object property (such as `_markers`) or method is private. Generally, you don't want to access private object members as they are only supposed to be used internally.

**Side note:**

If you search through the event's properties in your console, look through the prototype of the `layer` object and you'll find the `getAllChildMarkers` method:

[image: Layer prototype properties]

Comment: Perfect! I have overlooked this method. Many thanks!

Comment: No problem; glad to help! 

Comment: Any possible way to get markers outside of any event please? for example to call the openPopup() as a reaction for an external event to the map

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure, anything in the documentation related to this?